# How can I switch between tabs in a TabLayout programatically from within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

How can I switch between tabs in a TabLayout programatically from within a fragment which is currently displayed in the selected tab?
I have a button in my fragment which I want to switch to the other tab\fragment, and I can not use - `tabs.getTabAt(2).select();` because it does not work from inside the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it now and it was quite easy.
To switch tabs from within the fragment an access to the tabLayout is required and using `tabs = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);` worked just fine for that and then just call `tabs.getTabAt(1).select();` like snachmsm suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: glad I'm helped :)

Answer (score 1):

create method in your `Activity`

```
public void changeTab(int position){
    tabs.getTabAt(position).select();
}
```

and use in your `Fragment`

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).changeTab(2);
```

Comment: When I try and get a reference of the TabLayout "tabs"it seems as it shows the error - "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab.select()' on a null object reference" and just to make it clear, I did use findViewByID and everything, but it still considers it null.

Comment: `findViewById` must be called before above `changeTab` method call. also ensure that it is finding `TabLayout` successfully, your error suggests that `findViewById` fails finding `TabLayout`

Comment: `findViewById` is called before changeTab. bacuase changeTab is called when a button is clicked in the fragment, and findViewById is called in onCreate of the parent activity... it seems as it fails finding the TabLayout but I just can't figure out why....

Comment: your error says `...select()' on a null object reference"`, so `TabLayout` isn't null, `Tab` itself at `position` is null...